# How to avoid client's AdBlock block images?

Tags: javascript, adblock

We are now developing a web site,
we have some image link by outside source, like

```
<img class="comp_img" src="http://media-cdn......" />
```

it will be blocked, and add some attributions into `<img>` tag like

```
style="display: none !important; visibility: hidden !important; opacity: 0 !important; background-position: 0px 400px;"
```

I'm sure it's not AD, can I re-showing images by javascript?
My javascript may like..

```
function showAdblockImage() {
    //get all google ad elements
    var adsList = document.querySelectorAll(".comp_img");
    if (!adsList) { return; }
    for (var i = 0; i < adsList.length; i++) {
        if (adsList[i].innerHTML.replace('/\s/g', "").length != 0) {
            //AdBlock is not active, hence exit
            break;
        }
        //apply inline css to force display
        adsList[i].style.cssText = '';
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: do you have an example, that we can check?

Comment: @JeremyRajan What's example ? the image link ?

Comment: this image url will be blocked. http://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/02/d7/35/ea/the-sandbox-interactive.jpg

Comment: as in, a screenshot of your screen on how it is blocked. Is it blocked in a resource way (which every adblocker does) or they are made hidden? To, see what is happening on your screen...

Comment: I added it, please see my content.

Comment: Why do you even bother? Clients decided to mess with their pages, just let them do it.

Comment: @zerkms I think my boss would not accept this answer

Comment: Irregardless of how your boss wants that - you cannot do anything: if a client's browser for some reason wants to discard loading an image - it will. Learn being professional, your job is to explain how the web works.

Comment: remove the add block plus extension /plugin if you are using it.

Comment: If I were in your situation I would proxy blocked images.

Comment: ads might be blocked by image's SRC but also image's container (div, span, etc), status and attributes (class names, style, parent/child elements), could you send the complete HTML, just dump it somewhere (pastebin) and we could check what rule in the most common AdBlock list is targeting those ads, than you can rewrite some 'ignore rules' (`@@......`) and add them to your local-installation of AdBlock, unblocking worldwide will probably be a fail attempt, so you better give up right now, also- everyone hate ads!!!